# ImportError: cannot import name 'exporter_lib_v2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I have a problem when trying to generate the inference graph from my last saved checkpoint. I run:

```
python object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path C:/Train_Mask_RCNN/Tensorflow_API-Custom_Mask_RCNN/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_dir C:/Train_Mask_RCNN/Tensorflow_API-Custom_Mask_RCNN/CP/ --output_directory C:/Train_Mask_RCNN/Tensorflow_API-Custom_Mask_RCNN/IG
```

But it errors out saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exporter_main_v2.py", line 105, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter_lib_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'exporter_lib_v2'
```

The working directory is models/research and exporter_lib_v2.py is in its place as intended. What seems to be the problem here? Is there any other way to generate the IG? Thank you.

Comment: Did you followed steps as mentioned in the tutorial? Can you try as `python object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py --input_type=image_tensor --pipeline_config_path=C:/Train_Mask_RCNN/Tensorflow_API-Custom_Mask_RCNN/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_dir= C:/Train_Mask_RCNN/Tensorflow_API-Custom_Mask_RCNN/CP/ --output_directory= C:/Train_Mask_RCNN/Tensorflow_API-Custom_Mask_RCNN/IG` and let us know?

Comment: Thank you for your response @TFer2. The solution is to change the import code at line 105 in exporter_main_v2 from `from object_detection import exporter_lib_v2` to simply `import exporter_lib_v2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question for someone that is looking for a solution, you need to edit the code inside exporter_main_v2.py in your models/research/object_detection folder at line 105 from

`from object_detection import exporter_lib_v2`

to

`import exporter_lib_v2`